# NSURLProtectionSpace - Handling sub directories in the same host

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlcredentialstorage

Is there anyway to store the sub directory when the protection space is saved in the `NSURLCredential` storage.

Tried

1. subclassing `NSURLProtectionSpace` but no result of accessing the
   property.
2. adding the postfix to the host property and retrieving
   the domain by splitting the string of the host. but this results in
   duplicating same protection space in
   `NSURLCredentialStorage`; one for the host with postfix and one for
   the host without postfix

The requirement is to have separate protection space for two virtual domains under the same host.

Ex: http://example.com/vdomain1 and http://example.com/vdomain2

need to check the domain when looking for the credentials for the particular.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anyone who faced similar challenge or have experience on this?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone has the same issue, here's the solution.

You could use realm property in NSURLProtectionSpace for this purpose.

Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/67979/what-is-the-technical-definition-of-a-realm